# Trying to understand ともなく and ともなし

Tags: grammar

I’ve understand the construction is verb(dictionary form) + ともなく
To mean did something unintentionally

But the I’m just a little confused when it comes to interrogative words  I know the construction is Interrogative word + particle + ともなく

I am having trouble with these words I want to know what they mean since it seem like they have similar meaning
どこからともなく
どこへともなく
いつからともなく

Comment: Is there something regarding ともなし you wanted to ask?

Comment: Yeah just how to use it with interrogative words and what do the words -どこからともなく -どこへともなく -いつからともなく mean

Comment: And is ともなし the same as ともなく

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F/#je-55080

Comment: "And is ともなし the same as ともなく" - this point is purely grammatical. This なし is just an older form of ない (still seen in many expressions), and なく is the continuative form.

Answer (score 1):

ともなく practically adds *I-don't-know*/*nobody-knows*/*not-particularly*.

- どこからともなく - from nobody-knows-where / from nowhere
- どこへともなく - to nobody-knows-where
- いつからともなく - since nobody-knows-when / since I-don't-remember-when

Similarly なぜともなく=for no reason etc.

---

Slightly more grammatically a longer version would be どこからということもない.

First note the construction ...ということもない/ということはない, which means *It's not that ....*　So どこからともない would mean *It's not that the thing came from a particular place (as far as I know)*, where the thing is understood from the context. The ending ともなく makes it adverbial, meaning *Not that I know where the thing came from...*, for which *from nowhere* would work in most cases.

---

As for ともなし, it is used as a nominal phrase as commented. どこからともなく is equivalent to どこからともなしに, どこへともなく to どこへともなしに etc.

Comment: You have not described ともなし, which would be classical form of modern ともない, but in modern usage なし remains but as noun, and is used adverbially with に: ともなしに.